# Junit test method calling actual service method

Tags: java, mockito, spring-boot-test, reactive-streams

**Controller**

```
  @PostMapping("/event/confirmation")
  public Mono<CallbackResponse> eventConfirmation(@RequestParam("eventId") String eventId,
      @RequestBody ExecutionSummary execSummary, @RequestHeader("customerCode") String customerCode)
      throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    return eventService
        .updateEvent(eventId, execSummary, serviceAuthClient.getDefaultJwtTokenObserver().getJwtAccessToken())
        .flatMap(event -> {
          return Mono.just(new CallbackResponse(true));
        });
  }
```

**Test Class**

```
  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @WebAppConfiguration
  @AutoConfigureMockMvc
  @SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.main.banner-mode=off")
  public class EventStreamControllerTest {

      @Mock
      private ServiceAuthClient serviceAuthClient;
      @Mock
      private EventService eventService;

      @InjectMocks
      private EventStreamController eventStreamController;

      @Before
      public void setUp() {
      Mockito.reset(eventService);
          mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(eventStreamController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new ControllerExceptionHandler()).build();
      }

      @Test
      public void testEventConformation() throws Exception {

          ExecutionSummary executionSummary = new ExecutionSummary();
          executionSummary.setErrorMessage("Test");

          Mono<Event> event = Mono.just(new Event());
          Mockito.when(eventService.updateEvent(Mockito.anyString(), 
                  Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyString()))
                  .thenReturn(event);

          RequestBuilder requestBuilder = 
                          MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/event/confirmation")
           .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("customerCode", "456")
           .param("eventId", "123")
           .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(executionSummary));

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(),result.getResponse().getStatus());

  }
}
```

When i run the test it's actually calling original service it's not using mock service.
Can someone help me how to write a test for above controller method.

When i print the mock service invocations it's printing below output.

```
  [Mockito] Unused stubbings of: eventService
  1. eventService.updateEvent("", null, "");
  - stubbed -> at com.endpoint.rest.controller.EventStreamControllerTest.testEventConformation(EventStreamControllerTest.java:158)
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in your tested controller if it does call the method and with which parameters? And on which object, is it the `eventService` mock you're preparing in your test?
It would be best you show the whole relevant test class code around this method, including declarations and setup.

Comment: You  should how more about the test part : how you declare/init the mock and how you configure the test runner

Comment: @daniu I am added the whole test class in my post

Comment: It looks like the `serviceAuthClient` does not get mocked, which begs the question what `serviceAuthClient.getDefaultJwtTokenObserver().getJwtAccessToken()` returns. Is it `null`?

Comment: i also mocked the ServiceAuthClient

Comment: Try mocking them with `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`. Also you need to mock the `serviceAuthClient.getDefaultJwtTokenObserver()` call. Also you should try the breakpoint thing.

Comment: thanks it's working

Answer (score -1):

In you test class, you should define your `eventService` as a `MockBean`. Then it will be a mock service.

```
@MockBean
private EventService eventService;
```